# How to specify order of destructors call?

Tags: c++, sdl

I would like to write a simple game using SDL 2.0, and its structure looks kind of like this:

- class Engine, which will initialize SDL(SDL.Init() ) in its constructor, call SDL_Quit() in destructor, and contain instances of Window and Texture
- class Texture - wrapper class for SDL_Texture* . Creating texture when created, destroying texture in destructor
- class Window - wrapper class for SDL_Window, creating SDL_Window* and SDL_Renderer* at beggining, deleting in destructor.

Now, from what I know, SDL_Quit() unloads dll, closes all subsystems, etc. If I understand correctly, then if I call SDL_Quit(), calling SDL_DestroyWindow(), SDL_DestroyRenderer() and SDL_DestroyTexture() may have no effect or cause bug, because systems have been unloaded as well as dll.

Therefore, I would like Texture and Window inside Engine to be destroyed in the beggining of Engine's destructor, before SDL_Quit() is called.

When I tried simulating it on a simple class example, I got simple LIFO response:

> ClassOne object initialized
>
> ClassTwo object initialized
>
> Aggregate object initialized
>
> Aggregate object destroyed
>
> ClassTwo object destroyed
>
> ClassOne object destroyed

And it isn't what I want. I managed to get solution to my problem using pointers and dynamic memory allocation. I simply create them using operator new in Aggregate's constructor, and destroy them, using operator delete in destructor.

But, is there other way to do it, not involving pointers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your actual code, and consider using some [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). Perhaps consider using [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

Comment: Be `A` and `B` some classes, for `class Foo{ public: Foo(){ /*hello*/ } ~Foo(){ /*bye*/ } private: A a; B b; };`, when you create a `Foo` object it will always construct `a` (call `A::A()`), then construct `b`, then do `/*hello*/`, _in that order_; and when the object is destroyed it will always do `/*bye*/`, then destroy `b`, then destroy `a` (call `A::~A()`), in that order (i.e. the reverse order of construction). So in your current design it seems that you have a problem for destruction _and_ construction: you'll try to create SDL_Window and SDL_Texture _before_ SDL_Init().

Comment: @up Ow, that's true, didn't see this one. So am I forced to use pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not involving pointers:

If you have (assume `#include <iostream>`)

```
class Window {
public:
    Window() { std::cout << "W "; }
    ~Window() { std::cout << "~W "; }
};

class Texture {
public:
    Texture() { std::cout << "T "; }
    ~Texture() { std::cout << "~T "; }
};
```

and you want an order corresponding to output `Init W T` and `~T ~W Quit`, then, instead of that:

```
class Engine {
public:
    Engine() { std::cout << "Init "; }
    ~Engine() { std::cout << "Quit "; }
private:
    Window w;
    Texture t;
};
```

(which does `W T Init` and `Quit ~T ~W`), do this:

```
class Initializer {
public:
    Initializer() { std::cout << "Init "; }
    ~Initializer() { std::cout << "Quit "; }
};

class Engine {
public:
    Engine() { /* nothing */ }
    ~Engine() { /* nothing */ }
private:
    Initializer i;
    Window w;
    Texture t;
};
```

Comment: I would vote up if I had enough reputation. This is the way, thank you very much! You have been most helpful.

Comment: @DyP By "use a base class", do you mean `class Engine : private Initializer { ...` (and remove the member `i` of course)? i.e. using private inheritance instead of composition? If yes, it's indeed an alternative.

Comment: @gx_ Yes. You'd have to be careful (and document) that no member is declared before `Initializer i;` if you use composition. (Actually, this problem sounds like a job for a `shared_ptr`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you order the classes properly you get the desired destruction order:

In a class:

```
class X {
   public:
   X()
   // This order is not relevant and should produce a compiler warning
   : ..., c(), b(), a()
   {}


   private:
   // The members are initialized in this order and destructed in the opposite order.
   A a;
   B b;
   C c
   ...
}
```

Same applies for static instances in a single(!) translation unit: Construction in and destruction in reverse order of definition.

If you have multiple translation units the order each unit is initialized is not specified. Having static data in a function, eases it up - the data is initialized in the first function call.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, I wanted to initialize variables in constructor(at the end of constructor), and destroy them just at the beginning of destructor - order doesn't really matter, they just need to be destroyed in destructor, at the beginning.